# Timeout and adding class

Tags: jquery, hover, timeout

I try to add class to element when mouse is longer than 2seconds over it. Only then, if mouse is for example 1.5sec and then move to another the timer is cleared.

In other words:
It should expand my menu only when somebody is 2seconds over element:

```
    var timeoutId;

$("#block_top_menu .sf-menu > li > ul > li").hover(function() {
    if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null;
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        }, 2000);
    }
}, function() {
    if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

but that code doesn't add this class. Could somebody help?

Comment: this won't work on any touch device (iOS, Android) you should really look into [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim), if you can confirm you are okay with it not working on touch devices i'll happily provide an example answer.  Please provide sample HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, inside `timeOut`, `this` points to `window` object (*`window.setTimeout`*), not the element which was hovered. You have to cache it.

```
 var timeoutId;
$("#block_top_menu .sf-menu > li > ul > li").hover(function () {
   $this = $(this);
   if (!timeoutId) {
       timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
           timeoutId = null;
           $this.addClass("hover");
       }, 2000);
   }
}, function () {
   $this = $(this);
   if (timeoutId) {
       window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
       timeoutId = null;
       $this.removeClass("hover"); // Assuming you want to remove it after clearing interval?
   } else {
       $this.removeClass("hover");
   }
});
```

*Side note: You don't actually have to go through the trouble of manually nullifying timeOuts, modern browsers does a good job at garbage collection AFAIK*

Answer (score 0):

A good note from abc123 about touch devices. But if this is not your case, I'd suggest doing like this:

```
var timeoutId;

$("#block_top_menu .sf-menu > li > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        $(e.target).addClass("hover");
    }, 2000);
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7zyyvfmr/) with button (since I don't have your markup).